# python: subsetting and renaming columns by name in list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes, all with the same columns.  I wish to first select a subset of the columns and then rename the columns.

I have a list of columns on which to subset

```
rename_cols_list = ['Portfolio', 'CalendarYear', 'Count']
```

and apply a dictionary to change the column names:

```
rename_cols_dict = {'Portfolio': 'Index',
                    'CalendarYear': 'Year', 
                    'Count': 'Constituents'}
```

This works as expected when when applied to a single data frame in the list:

```
cdx_analysis = cdx_analysis[rename_cols_list].rename(rename_cols_dict, 
                                                     axis='columns')
```

But fails, i.e. no columns are subset and no changes are made, when I loop through a list of dataframes:

```
base_df = [cdx_analysis, cdx_ex_commod_analysis, cdx_commod_analysis,
           itraxx_all_analysis, itraxx_nonfins_analysis, itraxx_fins_analysis]

for df in base_df:
    df = df[rename_cols_list].rename(rename_cols_dict, axis='columns')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are juut resetting the loop variable in your loop to a new dataframe, not actually updating the list (think references/pointers). The easiest solution is to use the `inplace` flag:

```
for df in base_df:
    df[rename_cols_list].rename(rename_cols_dict, axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks but this also doesn't appear to work.  I have tried renaming inplace, exactly as you have specified, but no changes are made

Comment: @user I don't understand what you mean. Did you change the loop exactly to the above?

Comment: @user2845013 - Do you remove `df = ` ? It should working nice.

Comment: Thanks, yes I did use your code exactly as specified.

Comment: I appreciate that I need to drop the df= assignment when using inplace=True but when running the code either the columns are neither dropped, nor are the names  changed

Comment: @user2845013 Please edit into your question a minimal initialization of a data frame list (just a one row thing with some columns in each, could even be the same) and some code you are expecting to update it but does not work, then comment here and I'll take a look.